# Wi-Fi keeps on disconnecting randomly

Tags: networking, network-interface

I use Arch Linux with the Linux Zen kernel (5.14.15) and my Wi-Fi keeps on disconnecting when using Wi-Fi...

Note I also use a 3 AP mesh network.

In dmesg I was able to find out this error message:

```yaml
[  927.346066] wlo1: disconnect from AP [redacted]:b4:dd for new auth to [redacted]:b4:de
[  927.380432] wlo1: authenticate with [redacted]:b4:de
[  927.382507] wlo1: send auth to [redacted]:b4:de (try 1/3)
[  927.408763] wlo1: authenticated
[  927.409333] wlo1: associate with [redacted]:b4:de (try 1/3)
[  927.411476] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from [redacted]:b4:de (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[  927.416318] wlo1: associated
```

I also found this while trying to debug the issue:

```yaml
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: expected hw-decrypted unicast frame for station
```

Let me know if there's anything else you need and things I can try to fix these random disconnects, it gets pretty annoying when I try to play a game or I'm in a call with someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal functionality, not error messages; it disconnects from your …:dd AP to connect to you …:de AP. Basically, you roamed from one to the other, probably because some external movement changed the wireless channel between your APs and you, or becuase …:dd decided you should switch over to …:de.

Also, looking at the time stamps, this happens within 70 ms, so um, that's probably not something you will ever notice, even if you were a professional Starcraft player… your latency increases by 70ms, for 70ms, then is essentially back to normal.

Comment: There isnt any external movement changes that happen, is there a way to maybe set the threshold higher? Or maybe make it stick to one?
Also I am ussualy able to notice it since it happens a lot...

Comment: There might be settings on your APs, not on your computer.

Comment: How come this is fine on other devices, I dual boot windows and this problem never seems to appear there.

Comment: because on windows you don't see the logs. this really isn't relevant to your usage if `dmesg -w` isn't flowing faster than you can look with these messages - it's only a problem for 70 ms! If it happens once every couple of seconds, still not a problem. Maybe you're not showing the relevant part of the logs, where your reconnection actually does not work on the first attempt?

Comment: Sometimes when i load a site it give the dns error, during splitgate i had several disconects, I was screen sharing on discord and in the course of 5 min I had a few disconects from the call due to my wifi disconecting and reconecting. Even if it wouldnt be affecting me i would want it fixed..

Comment: Again, the logs you're seeing are not what's causing these problems. In the logs you've shared, you don't get disconnected, you get roamed, that's a fine thing and happens all the time, transparently. There might be other things happening that we don't know – we only see what you've shared, and what you've shared is normal operation, not a drop of connectivity.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to provide? Also check the edited post I was able to find something else in dmesg.

Comment: yeah, none of this is a "disconnect" without an immediate reconnect (which is not a disconnect in a user-facing way; it's just as if you're walking around with your phone and your phone switches between cells: you don't notice, it doesn't interrupt anything).  So, you could try to find a log entry where the time difference between disconnection and connection is not less than 100 ms. `dmesg --time-format delta` might be useful for that!